# Which Bliki (Blog+Wiki) solution can you recommend?

Tags: cms, blog, wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/which-content-management-system-cms-should-i-use)

I'm searching for a good [Bliki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bliki) solution, meaning a combination of blog and wiki that I can install on my own web space. I would like to be able to write articles in the wiki style much like with media wiki. So I want to use a wiki markup language, have a revision history, comments, internal links to other pages (maybe in other languages) and be able to collaboratively edit the articles. On the other side I would like to have a blog-like view on my articles, showing new articles (and changes to existing articles) in a time ordered fashion.

It would be nice if it would be possible to search through the articles and also tag the articles, so one could generate a tag cloud for the articles. A nice feature would also be to be able to order the articles according to views or even a voting system for the articles. Good would also be a permission system to keep certain articles private, showing them only to people logged in to the platform.

Apart from these nice to have features an absolute must have feature for the Bliki platform I'm searching is the possibility to handle math equations (written in LaTeX syntax) and display them either as pictures like media wiki or even better using Mathjax.

At the moment I'm using a web service called wikiDot which offers some of the mentioned features, however the free version shows to much advertisements, the blog feature is not mature, the design is quite ugly and loading of the page is often slow. So I want to install a Bliki solution on my own webspace. Can you recommend any solution for that?

Comment: Those two goals seem contradictory. Wikis are designed to be dynamic and in a state of constantly being revised and edited. Most articles are gradually built up over time. Blog articles are static. They're read chronologically, and only the latest articles are displayed on the homepage, so they have to be finished when they're published. Publishing wiki articles on a blog would mean users would only read the first edit of each article, or they'd be reading the same article multiple times.

Comment: In the confluence wiki there is a view, where every time a user adds or changes an article it is listed in time ordered fashion like in a blog. And I think that is useful. Of course if you would do that for Wikipedia, with I guess 1000 changes per minute, such a view would not be useful. But for a private blog it is ok. Also the user is not forced to read an article again, if it shown, that the article was only changed. So the blog view should show e.g. the first 20 lines of a new article, but only a small message if an existing article has been changed.

Comment: They're not forced to read them again, but when they view the blog feed or visit the homepage, they'll keep encountering old articles. I just think wikis are best suited to reference material (e.g. documentation, encyclopedias, etc.) that people won't care to browse in a chronological fashion. Instead, users will just search for the info they need. You can still have collaborative editing before publishing, but most blog articles aren't really something that would benefit from anyone being able to come along and edit after they've been published.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a place to start:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki/

You would have the best chance of being able to feed the wiki updates, entries, etc into your date ordered blog posts.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikilog extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikilog) adds some blog-like features to [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/).  To quote from the extension page:

> "The extension provides the extra functionality for wikilogs and wikilog articles. Wikilog articles inherit all the usual wiki functionality, like wiki syntax, edit history, page categories, talk pages, etc. Among the features added by the extension are: automatic listing of articles, setting of article authors, handling of article comments, generation of syndication feeds (Atom and RSS) for individual wikilogs and for all wikilogs of the wiki, etc. For more information, see the [full list of features](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikilog/Features).
>
> The philosophy of Wikilog is not to just make a blog out of a wiki, but to combine both concepts. Unlike most blogs, wikilog articles can be collaboratively written and published by multiple users. Talk pages of wikilog articles provide a simpler interface for commenting than standard MediaWiki talk pages. It is similar to most blog software, with the addition of discussion threading."

Ps. If you don't like MediaWiki's [built-in TeX support](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Math), here's a [MathJax extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax) for MediaWiki too.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try tikiwiki or bitweaver - both are large community based sites for users to each have their own blog and add to the wiki. They are a bit cumbersome, but I haven't looked into them for over a year.